# Access php application results in 403

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP backend on my local machine. The easiest way to test is to put my files in `XAMPP/htdocs`. Now, I can reach my application in the browser via `http://localhost/myapp/`?.

But trying to visit the app via `127.0.0.1/myapp` or `[IP_ADDRESS]/myapp`
results in 403 forbidden error.

It should especially work with my ip adress because I want to be able to visit the page on my android phone too.

I am working on macOS and using XAMPP.

Comment: Please share `vhost configuration` .  `.htaccess` if you are using `htaccess`.

Comment: try this **http://localhost/myapp/your-file-name.php** or you need index.php in your myapp folder.